# Console output in cmd.exe, and powershell.exe through C++

Tags: c++, powershell, console, cmd

I know a simple way for correct displaying of localized chars on `Cmd.exe`. But how can I do same for `Powershell.exe`?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(GetACP());
    SetConsoleOutputCP(GetACP());

    // valid output in cmd.exe, 
    // but invalid output in powershell.exe
    cout << "Привет мир (1)!" << endl; 

    // invalid output in both variants: cmd.exe, 
    // and powershell.exe
    wcout << L"Привет мир (2)!" << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output? Is your font supporting those glyphs?

perhaps the following link may be useful (about cmd.exe):

http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-add-and-change-fonts-in-windows-command-prompt.html

You could also try to redirect output from powershell to a file and check that. If the file is correct, you have a console-font not supporting your characters.

there is also a blog from ms, showing how to customize the font (about ps)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/10/16/windows-powershell-font-customization.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that's there's a shortcut to enable *proper* `wcout` handling in Windows. Try to add that as a first line to your `main`:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
```

After that `wcout << L"Привет мир (2)!" << endl;` will work like a charm independently of current locale and single-byte encoding chosen by user (as it *should*).